# disable prettyphoto close when click off

Tags: prettyphoto

Hi does anyone know how to disable the auto close when you click the page behind in prettyPhoto?

I have a div that opens when the page loads its about 200px square and I don't want it to close until the user clicks a button inside it.

At present when the user clicks away from it. prettyPhoto closes.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
jquery.prettyPhoto.js

}).bind("click", function () {
    //if (!settings.modal) e.prettyPhoto.close()
});
```